# Different results between R fast.prcomp PCA and scikit-learn PCA

Tags: python, r

I use the same test date on R and python scikit-learn, but i get different result. The pca result is not same，why this problem outcome？

```py
pca = PCA(svd_solver = "full")
dset = pd.read_csv("test2.xx",sep="\t",header=-1)
dsetT=dset.T
mda = dsetT.values
pc = pca.fit_transform(mda)
pd.DataFrame(pc)
```

```
output is 

Out[48]: 
          PC1       PC2        PC3           PC4
0  351.799662  4.557416 -1.189715  1.073466e-14
1 -252.647289  9.323494 -0.779368  1.073466e-14
2  -69.279448 -8.566973 -7.117057  1.073466e-14
3  -29.872925 -5.313937  9.086141  1.073466e-14
```

```
data.pca = fast.prcomp(data,retx=T,scale=F,center=T)
a = summary(data.pca)
pc = as.data.frame(a$x)
```

```
output is:

> pc
          PC1       PC2        PC3           PC4
X1 -351.79966 -4.557416 -1.1897154 -1.243450e-14
X2  252.64729 -9.323494 -0.7793682 -1.865175e-14
X3   69.27945  8.566973 -7.1170574  5.329071e-15
X4   29.87292  5.313937  9.0861409  1.532108e-14
```

Comment: the PC value is opposite, random is not the problem, i think

Comment: Principal components are entirely equivalent if the sign is swapped, so PC1,2,3 are to all intents and purposes identical.  PC4 is probably so close to being insignificant that rounding is affecting it, but you can probably treat it as zero anyway.

Comment: +1 @AndrewGustar, it does not matter if the sign of all the values of a component is multiplied `*-1`, this just means the component is rotated. The result is equally valid.

Comment: thank you for your explain about the PC value ,when i draw a scatter point picture, the different PC value will show different result, so R PCA result and python result ,which should i chose ?

Comment: @yueyao It doesn't matter which you choose - they are both correct, just the same thing looked at from different points of view.